# HTML page not displaying when called from backend using springboot and thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have this controller file code. This accepts data from the frontend in the form of @RequestParams. Once I have received the values, I am trying to call another html file called cart .html by adding an attribute using the addAttribute function in models.

```
@GetMapping("/cart")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getIfBorrowedBook(Model model, @RequestParam List<Integer> bookIds) {
        System.out.println(bookIds);
//      if(ifBorrowed.equals("on")) {
//          Books book = booksService.findById(bookId);
//          book.setIfBorrowed(true);
            
//          booksService.save(book); 
        List<Books> booksInCart = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Integer id:bookIds) {
            
        booksInCart.add(booksService.findById(id));
        
            
        }
        System.out.println(booksInCart);
    model.addAttribute("booksInCart", booksInCart);

        return "cart";  
        
    }
```

This is my cart.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>List Books</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container text-center">
    <h1>
        Cart
    </h1>
     
    <div>
   
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
             
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Genre</th>
                    <th>Author</th>
                    <th>Edition</th>
                    
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr th:each="book: ${booksInCart}">
                   
                    <td th:text="${book.title}">Title</td>
                    <td th:text="${book.genre}">Genre</td>
                    <td th:text="${book.author}">Author</td>
                    <td th:text="${book.edition}">Edition</td>
                    <td>
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
             <div>
               
            </div>
        </table>
       
    </div>

</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

This is the show_filtered books file that has a form which is submitted to the controller get request once a buttom is clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>List Books</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container text-center">
    <div>
        <h1>
        <div th:text="'Books on '+${filteredBooks[0].genre}"></div>
        </h1>
    </div>
     
    <div>
    <form th:action="@{/cart}">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
             
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Genre</th>
                    <th>Author</th>
                    <th>Edition</th>
                    <th>Borrow Book</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr th:each="book: ${filteredBooks}">
                   
                    <td th:text="${book.title}">Title</td>
                    <td th:text="${book.genre}">Genre</td>
                    <td th:text="${book.author}">Author</td>
                    <td th:text="${book.edition}">Edition</td>
                    <td>
                        
                        <input type="checkbox" name="bookIds" th:value="${book.bookId}" th:checked="${book.ifBorrowed}"/>
                        
                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
             <div>
               <a href="cart">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </table>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

But when I try to return the cart string at the end of getIfBorrowed() method, I am not getting the cart.html file. I am just getting a string that says cart on the webpage. This cart.html file is location in src/main/resources/templates. Therefore spring mvc should automatically be able to recognize the file but it does not do so.

Comment: What do you think `@ResponseBody` does...

Comment: sorry im still new to this, I have removed the @ResponseBody annotation.

Comment: Yes as that is to be used for REST services, also don't use `@RestController` but a regular `@Controller` annotation.